# How to rename Virtual Desktops in Windows 10 v1511?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit, virtual-desktop, windows-10-v1511

With the v1511 version update on Windows 10 Virtual Desktops now are named with quotation marks. Does this mean that you can rename them now?

[image]

I also discovered a registry key called "VirtualDesktopIDs" under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\VirtualDesktops
```

which changes, when you add Virtual Desktops and when you remove them.
I didn't try changing the key manually yet and can't find any documentation online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the quoted numbers on any of my machines. However, no, you still can't rename desktops. What you see in that registry key appears to just be a unique identifier, as it changes each time you remove and re-add a desktop.

I decided to run ProcMon while creating and removing desktops, and confirmed there was no registry key or file being used during that time that contained "Desktop 1", Desktop 2", etc. I suspect the names are generated on the fly and the "Desktop" part is hard-coded in a DLL somewhere. The only place I found those IDs referenced was in various keys under

> "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SessionInfo\1\ApplicationViewManagement"

which I presume are to keep track of which desktop applications were last opened in.